# How to create extensions for Custom Entities (.eti)

Tags: guidewire, gosu

We want to start using APD App on cloud for application and we have some entities that was created using APD in PC before(Coverable, Coverage entities etc.). Now we added some elements to those entities which are not possible to be added using APD. We want to create extensions for those entities and have our modifications done there, since the changes we do that is not synced with APD will be lost during re-generation of product.

The GW recommendation in this situation is to create a new eti entity and then to change its type to etx and name to the name of the entity you wish to extend. With some additional changes directly to the xml structure we were able to get this new extention entity to compile and be recognized by the system as an extention of the right entity, however, custom fields added to it were not visible to objects of the type, which rendered them useless as storing custom fields was the whole point.

As an alternative, we manually created an extention as an extention (as opposed to a new entity being used as an extention via name and type change) - this method works fine and Automated Cloud Assurance doesn't flag it in any way.

The question is then - does the second way satisfy GW standards and will not cause future issues, or is the first method (entity used as an extention) the preferrable one and there is some way to get it to work?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, APD creates an entity say A. You cannot modify A directly so you need to create an extension (.etx) for A and then add your custom fields to it. How is the Guidewire recommended approach different from your approach since effectively you are adding an etx whether by changing the XML directly or following the standard process? In fact, the first method seems absurd as you cannot have 2 etis for A at the same time, so the second entity will fail to compile until changed to an etx.

Comment: Exactly, it is recommended explicitly not to use an extension but an etx entity. However, you cannot create an extension for an entity that is in the extensions directory (.eti). After creating it as an entity with a different name and refactoring the name to be the same as the entity you want to create an extension for and changing .eti to .etx, then by manipulating XML, you can turn it into an extension. I wonder if that contradicts the 'don't create extension' recommendation.

Comment: An etx is an extension.  The problem is Studio does not let you create an Entity Extension on a custom entity (i.e. the new > Entity Extension wizard only lets you choose OOTB entities).  The suggestion appears to be to get around the Studio limitation by creating a separate entity then renaming it (you could also create the file manually from scratch like the good ole days).  In this case both Studio and Cloud standards are trying to protect the system, and the desired outcome, which should be allowed, is not possible.  I'm discussing with others, but it may be worth a support ticket?

Comment: Could you please provide more detail on the comment, "we added some elements to those entities which are not possible to be added using APD?"  What are these elements and why shouldn't they be synced to APD?  Is there an alternate solution to this, for instance, creating a separate entity and linking it to the APD entity with a one-to-one?

Comment: An example would be an array of some cost objects like Discount costs for a coverage. A one to many relation between a coverage or a coverable of those entities were generated by APD and an array of discount costs. Also we have a surepath accelerator implementation for Manuscript Endorsement which has a fk in APD generated entity which is being removed each time with re-generation.